# Browser History with ExtJS MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am looking for an example of ExtJs MVC which supports browser history. The example they have on the Sencha site [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs%3atab1%3asubtab1) is not MVC based.

The other one I found [here](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/01/extjs-mvc-dynamic-controller-view-model.html) uses dynamically loaded views and controller. I imagine the solution is a combination of the 2 approaches. Wondering if anyone has a ready example that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put together an example by combining the approaches from the 2 links above. Here is the jsfiddle with the ext js script: http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbaheti/zGXr6/3/

There are 2 views (tabs) - home and providers with corresponding history tokens

```
DemoApp.view.HomeTab
DemoApp.view.ProvidersTab
```

Each tab is managed by its corresponding controller that's responsible for creating an instance of the view and registering a history token.

```
DemoApp.controller.HomeController
//and its history token
this.uiToken = 'MainTabPanel,HomeTab';
```

The job of managing initial ui state is done by the application functions:

```
initializeHistoryHandling
setUiState
```

While the job of changing the history token on selecting tabs (by user action) is done by the main view controller:

```
DemoApp.controller.ViewportController:onTabpanelTabChange
```

This nicely manages the ui state based on the url and vice versa.